# Replacing variable text via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have very little knowledge of VBA and tend to record macros through EXCEL and work from there.  I have recorded this macro but instead of replacing specific text I want it to replace text found in any formulas with the text found in a specific cell

```
Sheets("Roulette Summary").Select
Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.Replace What:="Test case", Replacement:="Colin", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

So instead of looking for the specific text string 'Test Case' I want it to look for a text string I have inputted in a cell and replace it with another text string in another cell

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `Select` where possible. Set a variable to the value of a cell in your workbook. This can be on a different sheet. Then something like

```
Sub test()
Dim FindMe As String, UseMe As String

FindMe = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
UseMe = "Colin"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Roulette Summary").Range("J:J").Replace _
    What:=FindMe, Replacement:=UseMe, LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

If you set variables at the top of your code, it will be easy and quick to make changes to their values, so you don't have to find and replace stuff deep in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `.Select` method. Try the below code:

```
Sub Test()

    With Sheets("Roulette Summary")
        .Columns("J:J").Replace _
            What:=.Range("A1").Value, _
            Replacement:=.Range("A2").Value, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Put the string to be replaced into cell `A1`, and replacement string into `A2`.